# How to create N objects of different size classes with predictable number of allocations?

Tags: go

How do I create (one hundred thousand) 100000 instances of a size 8 class object in Go, such that the number of allocations (memstats.Alloc) approximately equals 800,000 (8 times 100000)

Note, I want to be able to use the same pattern to create 100000 instances of each size class object (16,24 etc) in Go, such that the number of allocations is a multiple of the size class (i.e. 100,000 * 16 etc), in addition to whatever the runtime creates on initialization.

Please use the following variables to  show the size class and the number of allocations (mstats.Alloc) and the number of objects (mstats.BySize[1].Mallocs) so that it's easy to see that the number of allocations is a multiple of the number of instances of the size class.

```
var mstats runtime.MemStats
runtime.ReadMemStats(&mstats)
log.Println(mstats.Alloc, mstats.Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 8;", mstats.BySize[1].Size, mstats.BySize[1].Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 16;", mstats.BySize[2].Size, mstats.BySize[2].Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 24;", mstats.BySize[3].Size, mstats.BySize[3].Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 32", mstats.BySize[4].Size, mstats.BySize[4].Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 48;", mstats.BySize[5].Size, mstats.BySize[5].Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 64;", mstats.BySize[6].Size, mstats.BySize[6].Mallocs)
log.Println("bySize 80;", mstats.BySize[7].Size, mstats.BySize[7].Mallocs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Admittedly, this answer is for the size 16 class only, but the example below ([playground demo](https://go.dev/play/p/_hyX9E7RHue)) shows a million mallocs (mstats.Mallocs) with a total of 16 million (16103864) total allocations (mstats.TotalAlloc 16 times 1 million), demonstrating the relationship between the size of the object and the number of total allocations and the number of instances of the object created.

```
type T struct{}

var Sink func()

func (t *T) Foo() {}

func (t *T) Bar() {
    Sink = t.Foo
}

func main() {

    t := new(T)

    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        t.Bar()
    }

    runtime.GC()
    var mem runtime.MemStats

    runtime.ReadMemStats(&mem)

    var mstats runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&mstats)
    log.Println("bySize;", mstats.Mallocs, mstats.Alloc, mstats.TotalAlloc) //2009/11/10 23:00:00 bySize; 1000097 103008 16103864

    log.Println("bySize;", mstats.BySize[0].Size, mstats.BySize[0].Mallocs)
    log.Println("bySize 8;", mstats.BySize[1].Size, mstats.BySize[1].Mallocs)
    log.Println("bySize 16;", mstats.BySize[2].Size, mstats.BySize[2].Mallocs)//2009/11/10 23:00:00 bySize 16; 16 1000013
    log.Println("bySize 24;", mstats.BySize[3].Size, mstats.BySize[3].Mallocs)
    log.Println("bySize;32", mstats.BySize[4].Size, mstats.BySize[4].Mallocs)
    log.Println("bySize 48;", mstats.BySize[5].Size, mstats.BySize[5].Mallocs)
    log.Println("bySize 64;", mstats.BySize[6].Size, mstats.BySize[6].Mallocs)
    log.Println("bySize 80;", mstats.BySize[7].Size, mstats.BySize[7].Mallocs)
}
```